# How to add an id to filename before extension?

Tags: python

I have a filename: name.ext

I want to do the following:

```
name + id + '.' + ext for name, ext in filename.split()
```

or find a better way to take a filename and add a random 7 character string to the end before the extension.

Here is what I have so far:

```
def generate_id(size=7, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))

def append_id(filename):
    return (name + '_' + generate_id() + '.' + ext for name, ext in filename.split('.'))
```

but it treats it as a generator expression, which is not my intended result.

What would be the correct way to write the `append_id` function?

Comment: `for name, ext in filename.split('.')` won't give you two successive elements of a collection in `name` and `ext`, but will try to unpack each collection's element into two variables: `name` and `ext`.

Comment: Yeah now I see the problem.  Was trying to do a list comp

Answer (score 44, accepted):

To do it in one line you can try:

```
def append_id(filename):
    return "{0}_{2}.{1}".format(*filename.rsplit('.', 1) + [generate_id()])
```

It's not very readable, though.

Most language implementations provide functions to deal with file names, and Python is no exception. You should use [os.path.splitext](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext):

```
def append_id(filename):
  return "{0}_{2}{1}".format(*os.path.splitext(filename) + (generate_id(),))
```

Note that the second version needs two additional modifications:

- `splitext` returns a tuple not a list, so we need to wrap the result of `generate_id` with a tuple
- `splitext` retains the dot, so you need to remove it from the format string

Still, I wouldn't struggle to have a oneliner here - see the next answer for more readable solutions.

Python 3.4 introduces [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib) module and you can use it like this:

```
from pathlib import Path

def append_id(filename):
  p = Path(filename)
  return "{0}_{2}{1}".format(p.stem, p.suffix, generate_id())
```

This will work for filenames without preceding path only. For files with paths use this:

```
from pathlib import Path

def append_id(filename):
  p = Path(filename)
  return "{0}_{2}{1}".format(Path.joinpath(p.parent, p.stem), p.suffix, generate_id())
```

In Python 3.9 there is also [`with_stem`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.with_stem), which might be the most suitable choice for this case.

Answer (score 37):

I'd suggest something plain and simple - use [`os.path.splitext`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) to retrieve basename and extension, and after that simple merge all result components via [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method.

```
import os
import random
import string

def generate_id(size=7, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))

def append_id(filename):
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    return "{name}_{uid}{ext}".format(name=name, uid=generate_id(), ext=ext)
```

Some testcases:

```
append_id("hello.txt")
append_id("hello")
append_id("multiple.dots.in.file")
```

Comment: Will this work if `filename` is a path like `C:/path/filename.txt`

Answer (score 22):

Since Python 3.4, a good tool for working with paths is [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html). This treats paths as ***objects*** instead of ***strings*** and offers a powerful interface.

Since Python 3.9, a new method - [`with_stem`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.with_stem) was added, so your function can be:

```py
from pathlib import Path

def append_id(filename):
    path = Path(filename)
    return path.with_stem(f"{path.stem}_{generate_id()}")
```

For older versions you can still use the [`with_name`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.with_name) method:

```py
from pathlib import Path

def append_id(filename):
    path = Path(filename)
    return path.with_name(f"{path.stem}_{generate_id()}{path.suffix}")
```

Those functions are generalized and will work also on full/relative paths and not just file names:

```
>>> append_id("sample.text")
PosixPath('sample_PBMQBFD.text')

>>> append_id("/a/b/c/sample.text")
PosixPath('/a/b/c/sample_UMTYXCP.text')
```

Note that a platform-specific `Path` object is returned. You can always just convert it back to a string with `str()`:

```
>>> str(append_id("/a/b/c/sample.text"))
'/a/b/c/sample_O1LPTEC.text'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def append_id(filename):
    parts = filename.split('.')
    return "".join(parts[:-1])+ '_' + generate_id() + '.' + parts[-1]
```

Answer (score 2):

your one line answer with the random generation -

`map(lambda x :x.split(".")[0] + "_" + hashlib.md5(("%.15f" % time.time())+"_"+''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for x in range(5))).hexdigest()[:7]+"."+x.split(".")[1], filenames)`

here you can input `filenames` as a list

just used a random id generation function which takes time and and random string of 5 characters md5's it and takes the first 7 characters from that.

It's not very readable but since you asked for a one line solution, I couldn't think of a more elaborate way.

Answer (score 2):

To fix your generate_id code, you need a list comprehension.

```
def generate_id(size=7, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits):
    return '_' + ''.join([random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size)])
```

Are you using python just to rename files? You can use a command line program like `pwgen` instead.

```
mv $filename ${filename/%.ext/_$(pwgen 6 1).ext}
```

If you are writing to file(s) from Python, consider using `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile` with the appropriate options. (delete=False, dir=".", prefix="...", suffix="...")

Comment: just to add a string to files that have the same name when being moved