# How to call a file name when I want to use a small portion of the name?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying for my code to pull a file when only a portion of the file name changes.

Example: I want to pull the file named `JEFF_1234.csv` where `1234` is an input from a GUI window.

The reason for the file name to have this structure is I want to have one main database that has multiple files for a specific part number. So if the user inputs a part number of `1234` and that will point to 4 files. `JEFF_1234.csv`, `SAM_1234.csv`, `FRED_1234.csv` and `JACK_1234.csv`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add an id to filename before extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37487758/how-to-add-an-id-to-filename-before-extension)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a way to update a template with some dynamic value.

A neat way to do this is to define a template string using curly brackets as place-holders for the content that will be generated at runtime.

```
jefffile_template = "JEFF_{t}.csv"
```

Then, once you've assigned a value to the unknown pointer, you can convert your template into an appropriate string:

```
jeff_filename = jefffile_template.format(t="1234")
```

Which will store the value of `JEFF_1234.csv` into the variable `jeff_filename` for usage later in your program.

There are other [similar ways](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/string.html#format-examples) of calling formatting functions, but using this ***by name*** style is my preferred method.

...and in case you're wondering, yes, [this was still valid in 2.7](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/string.html#format-examples).