# Python: Concatenate old csv filename with extra text and save it

Tags: python

I've written below code. but it saved second csv like "15.csv+ws.csv". I want it to save it like "15ws.csv". have there any way to do it?

```
fname = r"15.csv"
ap= open(f"{fname} + 'ws.csv'",'a') 
ap.write(" "+r) 
ap.close()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add an id to filename before extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37487758/how-to-add-an-id-to-filename-before-extension)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [pathlib](https://pypi.org/project/pathlib/) library.

```
from pathlib import Path
ap= open(f"{Path(fname).stem}ws.csv",'a')
```

It will save second csv with "15ws.csv" filename

Answer (score 2):

See this question:

- [Extracting extension from filename in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/541390/1609514)

Try this:

```
import os

fname = r"15.csv"

name, ext = os.path.splitext(fname)
ap = open(f"{name}ws{ext}", 'a') 
ap.write(" "+r) 
ap.close()
```